# Anaconda Navigator Windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda

After cmd: anaconda-navigator in the command line i am getting following errors.
I tried updating conda, resetting conda as well.

**ERROR**

(base) C:\Users\Lenovo\Anaconda3\Scripts>anaconda-navigator
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\Anaconda3\Scripts\anaconda-navigator-script.py", line 10, in 
    sys.exit(main())

File "C:\Users\Lenovo\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\app\main.py", line 103, in main
    from anaconda_navigator.app.start import start_app

File "C:\Users\Lenovo\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\app\start.py", line 34, in 
    from anaconda_navigator.widgets.main_window import MainWindow

File "C:\Users\Lenovo\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\widgets\main_window.py", line 32, in 
    from anaconda_navigator.api.anaconda_api import AnacondaAPI

File "C:\Users\Lenovo\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\api\anaconda_api.py", line 34, in 
    from anaconda_navigator.api.client_api import ClientAPI

File "C:\Users\Lenovo\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\api\client_api.py", line 20, in 
    import binstar_client

File "C:\Users\Lenovo\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\binstar_client__init__.py", line 14, in 
    from .errors import *

File "C:\Users\Lenovo\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\binstar_client\errors.py", line 1, in 
    from clyent.errors import ClyentError

File "C:\Users\Lenovo\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\clyent__init__.py", line 10, in 
    from pkg_resources import iter_entry_points

File "C:\Users\Lenovo\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources__init__.py", line 3126, in 
    @_call_aside

File "C:\Users\Lenovo\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources__init__.py", line 3110, in _call_aside
    f(*args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\Lenovo\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources__init__.py", line 3139, in _initialize_master_working_set
    working_set = WorkingSet._build_master()

File "C:\Users\Lenovo\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources__init__.py", line 572, in _build_master
    ws = cls()

File "C:\Users\Lenovo\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources__init__.py", line 565, in **init**
    self.add_entry(entry)

File "C:\Users\Lenovo\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources__init__.py", line 621, in add_entry
    for dist in find_distributions(entry, True):

File "C:\Users\Lenovo\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources__init__.py", line 1968, in find_on_path
    for dist in factory(fullpath):

File "C:\Users\Lenovo\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources__init__.py", line 2038, in distributions_from_metadata
    root, entry, metadata, precedence=DEVELOP_DIST,

File "C:\Users\Lenovo\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources__init__.py", line 2495, in from_location
    py_version=py_version, platform=platform, **kw

File "C:\Users\Lenovo\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources__init__.py", line 2870, in _reload_version
    md_version = _version_from_file(self._get_metadata(self.PKG_INFO))

File "C:\Users\Lenovo\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources__init__.py", line 2459, in _version_from_file
    line = next(iter(version_lines), '')

File "C:\Users\Lenovo\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources__init__.py", line 2649, in _get_metadata
    for line in self.get_metadata_lines(name):

File "C:\Users\Lenovo\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources__init__.py", line 1414, in get_metadata_lines
    return yield_lines(self.get_metadata(name))

File "C:\Users\Lenovo\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources__init__.py", line 1411, in get_metadata
    return value.decode('utf-8') if six.PY3 else value

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x84 in position 0: invalid start byte

Comment: Have you tried conda update anaconda-navigator ?

Answer (score 0):

Try update navigator:

```
conda update conda
conda update anaconda-navigator
conda update navigator-updater
```

Then open anaconda-navigator. If that does not work, you can reset to navigator default and then try update:

```
anaconda-navigator --reset
conda update anaconda-navigator
conda update navigator-updater
```

If this does not work, then go extreme and restore your anaconda from your first installation

```
conda install --rev 1
```

You have to reinstall some of the packages that you installed after your initial installation.

Let me know if you got other errors